# How to convert decimal OR hexadecimal value to integer?

Tags: javascript

I receive a string which can be a number `'42'` or an hexadecimal number `'0x12'`. I would like to convert this to a number.

I currently have this very cumbersome function:

```
function str2num(str) {
    if (str.substr(0, 2) == '0x')
        return parseInt(substr(2, str), 16)
    else 
        return parseInt(str, 10)
}
```

Is there a shorter way to do that?

Comment: maybe read the documentation of [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). It can do more than you seem to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand properly you want convert anything to integer; so you can just use

`parseInt('0x12')`. It convert any type of variable to integer.